# how to test web applications for mobile devices on ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, ios

Is there any program like XCODE i can use on ubuntu to test web applications for iphones and iOS? I have ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: In what way do you meen like xcode, just a IDE to write code with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only doing web apps and not app store stuff, install this IDE

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Open Eclipse from dash and set it up how you like

Then install the plug in from [here](http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.2/024747/index.html)

The instructions for installing the Aptana plugin are

> Save the above file to an easy to find location. Open Eclipse, and go
>   to Help > Software Updates > Find and Install Search for new features
>     to install, then click "Next" then choose "New Archived Site". Choose
>   the file you saved in step 1. Select the appropriate plugins to
>   install, then click "Next", accept the license agreements, and click
>   "Next" again. Click "Change location". 
>      If no appropriate location is already available, click "Add Location" and choose something like
>   "D:\dev\extensions\pluginname" or "extesnions\aptana". Click "Finish".

If you really don't like the IDE a standalone version of Aptana is available from the same link can